# Android newr google-play-services.jar causing delay on startup

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, adview

I recently switch to the new google-play-services.jar as the old one is being phased out later this year. However when serving AdMob banner ads using adView.loadAd(request) in oncreate there is now a delay to the main UI which causes the app to sit on a blank screen for between 2 and 7 seconds.

From what I can see it appears this new version is using a webview and the delay is being caused by the time it takes to initialy load this widget. Subsequent ad request are not delayed probably because the webview component is cached.

You cannot load the ad request in background via runnable or async without getting a exception error.

Note: Reverting back to the previous library removes the delay.

This is the relevant code in OnCreate:

```
adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adMob2);
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(request);
```

Does anyone know a way round this without reverting back to the previous library?

Comment: I'm not alone: Android AdMob takes 4-5 to create AdView

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/LdUVIZ2AW6M

Comment: Do you have a sample app that reproduces this issue that you could share?

Answer (score 0):

The old version (6.4.1) also uses a WebView. I suspect it is something else in your app. If you switch back to the Amdob-6.4.1 do you still get the delay?

Comment: Note: Reverting back to the previous library removes the delay.